# Query sql to using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I trying to get the same result using pandas dataframe to retrieve the result

This is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT strftime('%m', date_report) as month, count(*) as total_infector 
from cases 
where  has_travel_history = 't' and age >= '50' 
group by month
order by total_infector desc limit 2
```

Using pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Data")

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_report'])

df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month

df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str)

df1 = df[df['age'] >= '50']
```

I manage to get age which is more than 50. Now I am trying to add in `AND` condition `has_travel_history = 't'`. Is there any way easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you can filter the DataFrame with one or more condition using the following syntax:

```
df[ (df['col_1'] == 'value_1') & (df['col_2'] == 'value_2')]
```

note that the '&' or 'AND' operator is used to concatenate multiple conditions. (similarly you can use the '|' to use the 'OR' condition.

In your case, the syntax should be:

```
df_1 = df[ (df['age'] >= '50') & (df['has_travel_history'] == 't')]
```

Now, to complete the rest of the Query using Pandas, use the 'groupby' function and the 'count' aggregator to get all the counts for each month.

```
df_1 = df_1.groupby(['month']).count()
```

Next, you need to sort your values in a descending order, simply use the 'sort_value' function.

```
df_1.sort_values('total_infector', inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Finally if you are interested in only the first 'n' (in this case 2) samples just use 'head' function

```
df_1 = df_1.head(2)
```

Last, but not least, you can select the columns you are interest in like this:

```
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()[['month', 'total_infector']]
```

- Note that the 'reset_index' function was used, because we had prevoiusly use the 'groupby' method on the 'month' column.

Comment: Note that the `()`'s here are very important